# LaTeX command help infomation in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

New to TeXstudio and LaTeX, can anyone suggest a convenient way to look for command help infomation like options in Texstudio?

Yesterday, I found that when I hold the cursor on a command for a time, then some help info appeared, but it seems it does not work all the time: today, no matter how long I hold the cursor, nothing appears.

Comment: Under `options` -> `Adv. editor` -> `Special options` -> `Show help as tooltip on text in editor`, do you have that box checked? What kinds of commands would you like the help info for?

Comment: Sorry I go to `Option` -> `Configure Texstudio`, but I did not find `Special options` and `Show help as tooltip on text in editor` in it, are you sure this is in Texstudio. I just find help info of general commands, like what what we get with `command --help`

Comment: On the bottom left of the `Configure Texstudio` window, did you check the `Show advanced options` box? Then `Adv. Editor` should show up on the left panel of options.

Comment: I see. I have enabled `Show help as tooltip on text in editor`, now I can see the command info when holding the cursor on commands, but problem is that the info is not complete, would you suggest how to display the full info?Thanks very much!

Comment: I don't know if such a functionality exists -- I may be wrong, but I don't think the tooltip help is meant to be comprehensive.